# Replace quotes in a python array or arrays

Tags: python, replace

I have a dict object in python:

```
'polygon': {'coordinates': [[['51.89600366973369,5.604579537426986'], ['51.88589816283178,5.598937488274174'], ['51.882074887477046,5.620585782912315'], ['51.891197214447004,5.622057621577596']]]}
```

I want to replace the ' from the coordinates with nothing so:

```
'51.89600366973369,5.604579537426986' becomes 51.89600366973369,5.604579537426986
```

How can I achieve that in python? To be honest, I don't now where to start.

Comment: That wouldn't be a valid data type, What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to convert them from str to float?

Comment: `map(float,str.split(','))`

Comment: You don't extract data from a dictionary by replacing characters. You use indexes and iteration to retrieve the information and then `print` it or convert it into an other format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0):

Yes now it's indeed an array with a string with geographic coordinates, but elasticsearch want the according the geojson format (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) which is not a string. The python function needs tranform the data and then stream it to elasticsearch.